# Strange behavior when query for varchar filed

Tags: mysql

I came across this strange behavior when I was hunting for a bug in a system. Consider following.

We have a mysql table which have varchar(100) column. See the following sql script.

```
create table user(`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,`user_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,`username` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,PRIMARY KEY (`id`),UNIQUE KEY `user_id` (`user_id`))  ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=129 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

insert into user(user_id, username) values('20120723145614834', 'user1');

insert into user(user_id, username) values('20120723151128642', 'user1');
```

When I execute following query I received 0 results.

```
select * from user where user_id=20120723145614834;
```

But When I execute following I get the result(note the single quote).

```
select * from user where user_id='20120723145614834';
```

This is expected since user_id field is varchar. Strange thing is that both following queries yield result.

```
select * from user where user_id=20120723151128642;
select * from user where user_id='20120723151128642';
```

Can anybody explain me the reason for this strange behavior. My MySql version is 5.1.63-0ubuntu0.11.10.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check mysql document [12.2. Type Conversion in Expression Evaluation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/type-conversion.html)

> Comparisons that use floating-point numbers (or values that are
>   converted to floating-point numbers) are approximate because such
>   numbers are inexact. This might lead to results that appear
>   inconsistent:

```
mysql> SELECT '18015376320243458' = 18015376320243458;
        -> 1
mysql> SELECT '18015376320243459' = 18015376320243459;
        -> 0
```

So we better use always right data type for SQL.